# Overlaying points on map in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt5

I have added google map with PyQt5 and PyQGIS and I want to overlay points and images on map(specifically in python code) but I don't know how to do that. I am using PyQt5 and QGIS3.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by *"I have created google map"*. Are you talking about a simple usage of a basemap or what? It is also not clear to me why do you need PyQt5? Regarding your point layer, in which format is it and how does the content of it look like? As well as what kind of images are talking about? Moreover, when asking for programming issues it is highly suggested to include a piece of your code that "does" what you want or at least intends. Can you please tell us more about your idea, inputs and the current state of your code.